# Get Mailbox Name using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have multiple Mailboxes, I need a msgbox that will pop-up the name of the active mailbox that I use to reply for specific email.

```
Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim mapifolder As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set mapifolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim myNamespace As Outlook.Name
    MsgBox oItem.Parent
    MsgBox mapifolder.Store.Name
End Sub
```

I got an error 91 on the 2nd msgbox

Any idea what is  missing on this?

Comment: Where is `mapifolder` assigned? Error 91 means you're making a member call `.Store` against an object (`mapifolder`) that wasn't `Set` with a valid object reference, hence its value is `Nothing`. Consider editing your question to include a self-contained [mcve].

Comment: I edited and added the declaration of Mapifolder. the only result I want is to have a pop-up msg containing the active mailbox name everytime i click  reply.

Answer (score 0):

The Namespace class doesn't provide the Store property:

```
Dim mapifolder As Outlook.NameSpace
Set mapifolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
MsgBox mapifolder.Store.Name
```

The `mapiFolder` is an instance of the `Namespace class`, not `Folder`.

To achieve the goal you need to use the following sequence of calls:

```
MsgBox oItem.Parent.Store.Name
```

Be aware, in case of root folders the `Parent` property returns an instance of the Namespace class. So, add a check to the final edition of the code.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried to add your suggested code and Error 438 appeared.

Comment: Try to cast the parent object to the Folder class first. Where did you get the `oItem` instance?

Comment: I declare it as a private event `Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem '